# Android: Custom Xml Attributes for PreferenceScreen

Tags: android, android-preferences

I use custom xml attributes for preferences. The preferences are inflated from xml.

I managed to create and read custom xml attributes for EditTextPreference, ListPreference and CheckBoxPreference by creating custom classes which inherit from the respective preference class.

In the constructor of the class I can read the attributes like so:

```
public class CustomTextPreference extends EditTextPreference {
    public CustomTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.PreferenceCustomAttrs);
        x = a.getString(R.styleable.PreferenceCustomAttrs_x);
        y = a.getString(R.styleable.PreferenceCustomAttrs_y);
    }
}
```

My problem is that I can't do this for the PreferenceScreen class, as it is a final class. So my question is: Is there any way I can read the custom attributes of a PreferenceScreen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not by the same techniques that you are using. Remember, though, that preference XML files are just XML resources. You can get a parser for the file via `getResources().getXml()` from your `PreferenceActivity`. From there, you can read whatever you want.

Comment: thank you for your answer! This would be an option, however with this approach the custom attributes wouldn't be member of the property class. I would have to maintain a manual mapping (eg. via a dictionary) from the property to its custom attributes, which i already do anyway and wanted to get rid of by the custom attributes.